# How does Jessica Jones drink but not get drunk?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

I have just watched a few episodes of the *Jessica Jones* show and couldn't help but notice that she drinks a lot of hard liquor. Yet we do not see her ever acting or feeling intoxicated. Why? Is that due to her special powers?

Comment: She's been shown to be affected by the alochol, just not fall-down drunk. Whether this is related to her powers or plain-old-alcoholism is unclear.

Comment: If you watch her closely, she is mostly shown towards end of her bottle, so we don't get to see how much she already had. Yet she keeps working and stays focused. Average human being cannot do that.

Answer (score 8):

Jessica has an alcoholic side to her personality which she uses to cope with her repeated tragedies. Due to her superhuman metabolism, she is able to consume vast quantities of alcohol without damage to her liver and appears to have high tolerance, being able to quickly drink an entire bottle of wine during dinner with Kilgrave's then nonchalantly asking for another one. When inebriated, Jessica can become more violent such as threatening Jeri Hogarth's ex-wife, Wendy to sign her divorce papers.

> ***Regenerative Healing Factor:***
>   Jones' augmented metabolism heals faster than an ordinary human being. She is capable of completely healing minor scratches and injuries in mere hours, and major injuries like broken ribs in just a single day. It may also allow her to not be affected by the harmful and long term affects of alcohol, leaving her only to experience intoxication and hangover while not experiencing any signs of toxicity.
>   -http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Jessica_Jones